# ContentEditable in Functional Component - list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

is there any chance to make only one item editable with this render ?

```
      <ul>
        {displayTasks.map(task => (
          <li key={iiud()}>
            <p contentEditable={edit}>{task}</p>
            <button onClick={handleEdit}>{buttonText}</button>{' '}
            <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
```

My edit code for now looks like this

```
 const [edit, changeEdit] = useState(false);
  const [buttonText, changeButtonText] = useState('Edit');

 const handleEdit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
    let editItem = e.target.previousSibling;
    console.log(editItem);
    changeEdit(!edit);
    buttonText === 'Edit' ? changeButtonText('Save') : changeButtonText('Edit');
  };
```

and of course after clicking the button every item is editable.

Comment: Instead of a boolean, you could keep the ID in `edit` If `edit` has no ID, then nothing is edited. Use an if statement to conditionally allow editing.

Comment: I've tried to but still don't how to change contentEditable to true only in one item

Comment: I wouldn't use content editable in react. They don't place nice

Comment: yeah, I tried to change text into input after button click but there is still the same problem - click on one button, changes all texts into input

Comment: `iiud()` must output the same ID for each task

Comment: nope, i've checked - ids are different

Comment: `e.target.previousSibling` this is out of place in a react component.

Comment: maybe, but that's not the case and doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Try to separate the "is editing" logic from the output HTML. It's being mixed together which I think it causing issues. `e.target.previousSibling` is one such confusion. In jquery it made sense. In react it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a state with the task ID that is currently being edited.

```
const [editTaskId, changeEditTaskId] = useState();

const handleEdit = e => taskId => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeEditTaskId(taskId);
    buttonText === 'Edit' ? changeButtonText('Save') : changeButtonText('Edit');
};

{displayTasks.map(task => (
     <li key={task.id}>
       <p contentEditable={task.id === editTaskId}>{task}</p>
       <button onClick={handleEdit(task.id)}>{buttonText}</button>{' '}
       <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
     </li>
))}
```

Comment: @OlaKozioł Have you added id to tasks?

Comment: no, I don't know where. I'm trying different things but nothing works

Comment: it's an array - when user ads task in form, this task is added to this array

Comment: @OlaKozioł you need add id to item from displayTasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205678/discussion-between-alexander-and-ola-koziol).